# qt get child (Callout) from QChart

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts, qchart

I implemented a custom Callout class like in this example [Callout Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtcharts-callout-example.html)

```
QPolarChart *chart = new QPolarChart();
Callout *callout = new Callout(chart);
```

If I have only access to chart (callout went out of scope), how can I regain access to callout. I thought about using

```
QObjectList children = chart->children();
```

but callout is not here. 
How can I get access to callout again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `childItems()`, this returns the `QGraphicsItem`s children.

```
 for(QGraphicsItem *childItem: chart->childItems()){
     if(Callout *c = dynamic_cast<Callout *>(childItem)){
         //use c
     }
 }
```